# Trying to make a hashset dynamic with recursive children to populate a Treeview from Mudblazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, hashset, mudblazor

I have a problem trying to fill a Mudtree from Mudblazor.

My current code is this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Devices = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Device>>("https://localhost:8443/api/device");
    DeviceGroups = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<DeviceGroup>>("https://localhost:8443/api/group");


    TreeItemData rootTreeItem = new TreeItemData("Root", Icons.Filled.Computer)
        {
            IsExpanded = true
        };
    TreeItems.Add(rootTreeItem);

    rootTreeItem.TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>() { };
    foreach (var group in DeviceGroups)
    {
        if (group.ChildGroups != null)
        {
            foreach (DeviceGroup childgroup in group.ChildGroups)
            {

                rootTreeItem.TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(group.Name, Icons.Filled.Computer)
                    {
                        IsExpanded = true,
                        TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>()
                    {
                        new TreeItemData(childgroup.Name, Icons.Filled.Computer)
                        {
                            IsExpanded = true,

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else if (group.ParentGroup != null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            rootTreeItem.TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(group.Name, Icons.Filled.Computer));
        }
    }

}
```

Now what the problem is that the child groups get added as main groups themselves, I am not sure how to recursively add children to a hashset. I am trying to have it look like a file explorer basically, but instead of files, it is simply groups and "devices".

I have been trying to wrap my head around it for around a week now and could not find a working solution.

[Mudblazor Mudtree showing the items all being main groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93c74.png)

I have to use a hashset because I am binding the data to a Treeview, from Mudblazor. The desired result would be something like this:

[Image showing the Treeview with recursive children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqxFH.png)

Here is an image of what the groups are like in the database:

[Image showing the database relations with the parent group IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zipHY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't work out your parent-first strategy for building your tree from your database (an unorganized list). If you're not going to get the database to order your data in a suitable fashion (so that every parent is encountered before it's children, for example) you'll need to handle a "ensure parent exists before child" in the client side. It might be simplest to load all your nodes into a memory that can look them up, then run over them again making the connections between nodes.

```
var map = new Dictionary<Guid, TreeItemData>();

//make a root note (the data in the db doesn't contain it)
map[Guid.Empty] = new TreeItemData("Root", Icons.Filled.Computer){ IsExpanded = true, TreeItems = new() };
TreeItems.Add(seen[Guid.Empty]);

var nodes = get_nodes_from_db....

//create a map that knows about every node in the data and maps to a TreeItemData
foreach(var node in nodes)
    map[node.GroupId] = new TreeItemData(node.Name, Icons.Filled.Computer){ IsExpanded = true, TreeItems = new() };

//now we know about every node, we can link parents to children
foreach(var node in nodes)
    map[node.ParentGroupGroupId].TreeItems.Add(map[node.GroupId]);
```

The first loop creates every node by its ID. The second loop can then be assured that any given ParentId does exist in the map so it can just straight up access it, and add the current TreeItem as a child of that parent treeitem

In essence `map` is an index from GroupId to a TreeItemData, so it makes it easy to say "lookup this parent X, then add this child Y to X's children"

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEcGEylQQgshnOUL

Comment: This is a perfect fix to my issue, very much appreciated. Only thing now is that my GetFromJsonAsync method to fetch from the database is null when it runs. Will attempt to fix that and will implement your fix!

Comment: You're not still writing those things by hand are you?! :D (take the swagger.json from the server, and run it through NSwag, so it does all that code for you , and you just call `var x = new SomeClient(); x.GetBlahBlah()`

Comment: Euhh.. maybe? I use this: DeviceGroups = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<DeviceGroup>>("https://localhost:8443/api/group");